# Unable to search in Generic list on the basis of string data type

Tags: c#, generics, search

```
        public string Process<T>(string name, string address)
    {
        var dataObj= new Data<T>();
        List<T> currentList= dataObj.GetAll(name);

    }
```

Now i want to search address in current list.
Client will call T like - 
Process(Domain)("pc1","172.17.2.1").
Domain class contains name and address properties.
GteAll will return all the values.

Comment: Is `Domain` a class under your control? Will all such `T` types be classes under your control?

Comment: Yes. Client will call Process and Pass Domain as T. Domain and other classes are at Servr end and values will be populated from xml file. Address is string value in Domain class.

Comment: What is the `Data<T>` class? And in fact, why is `Process` a generic method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
IEnumerable<T> myEnumerable = currentList.Select(current => current.address = address);
```